# Return list of names in bs4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract names in a div that are  preceded by hash tags.

```
<div class="h_names">#jason, #michael, #sam, etc...</div>
```

So my result would be a list of `jason`, `michael`, `sam`, etc..

Im not sure how I could do this with BeautifulSoup.

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'h_names'})
```

This finds the div but I need a regular expression to extract the name

Comment: check out the documentation on the site, if you'll be using bs4 in the future, it's definitely worth a read, and not too hard to grasp http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't use a regular expression, but I would contend that you don't need to use one, or import anything new, as `BeautifulSoup` provides you with inbuilt methods to extract the text from the html.

If the **div** was:

```
'<div class="h_names">#jason, #michael, #sam</div>' # without the etc.. bit
```

**Then:**

```
div = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'h_names'})
names = [str(name.strip()[1:]) for name in div.text.split(',')]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print names
['jason', 'michael', 'sam']
```

`names` was created using a [**list comprehension**](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

The conversion to strings (using `str()`) in the *list comprehension* was 
necessary as the `text` method on the div(`div.text`) returns unicode strings(like: `u'jason'`)

The string slicing of `[1:]` is used to slice off the first character of each string(the '#' in this case)

The `strip` method of strings(`str.strip()`), simply cuts off any leading or trailing white space, aswell as newline characters(`\n`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to match the criteria inside that `div` element.

```
import bs4
import re

soup  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
div   = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'h_names'})
names = re.findall(r'#([a-zA-Z]+)', str(div.text))
```

Output

```
['jason', 'michael', 'sam']
```